# Cartthrob subscriptions

Tags: ee2, cartthrob

I have recently purchased Cartthrob Subscriptions and am running into a few difficulties. I have tried support forums, contacting Cartthrob directly but i'm getting nothing back at all, which is strange as their support is usually amazing!

I have set up a subscription plan and set up token vaults on my Sage Gateway, however when testing, Cartthrob is processing the order as a standard product and not creating a subscription/subscriber. The details are all confirmed and going into Sage, but the subscription is not generated.

My add to cart form is as below:

```
{exp:cartthrob:plans}
  {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form 
    return="store/checkout"
    plan_id="{id}"
    subscription="yes"
    price="{price}"
    title="{name}"
    subscription_allow_modification="yes"
    subscription_interval_units="days"
    subscription_interval_length="1"
    subscription_price="10"
    subscription_total_occurrences="-1"
    subscription_name="{name}"
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />

    {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
{/exp:cartthrob:plans}
```

I have tried different options to try and make this work but I'm stuck, can't figure put why it isn't going through!

PS. using 1 day interval to test ;)

Any help appreciated, or any advice on how I can get hold of Cartthrob considering I have spent $300 on this module.

Thanks in advance
Ben

Comment: Which version of EE and CT is this? At present I don't believe that CT have updated CT Subscriptions to be compatible with EE 2.6.x as of yet.

Comment: Hi Ian. Thanks for your comment. EE version 2.2.5 and CT version 2.3.2?

Comment: did you ever get your subscriptions to work?